# GROUP BY in LDAP query

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ldap

Is there an equivalent of the GROUP BY syntax for LDAP queries. I am trying to return a list of the people and titles in a each department of a particular company. My code is:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript"%>
<% response.Buffer = True
dim ADUser 'Holds the OU
dim RecordList 'Holds the RecordList object
%>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--#include virtual="//includes/functions.asp"-->
<!--#include virtual="//includes/display.asp"-->
<h1>Organisational Structure</h1>
<div class="commandspace">
<p class="infotext">The org structure can be viewed with or without staff, indented or left justified.</p>
</div>
<% 
ADUser = "LDAP://OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=internal"
' Make AD connection and run query
Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
objCon.Properties("User ID") = "EXAMPLE\User"
objCon.Properties("Password") = "PaSsWoRd"
objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon
objCom.CommandText ="select company, department, givenName, sn, title, telephoneNumber FROM '"& ADUser &"' where company ='*' GROUP BY company" 
Set objRS = objCom.Execute
RecordList = objRS.GetRows()
' Loop over returned recordset and output HTML
for i = 0 to uBound(RecordList, 2)
    u = i + 1
    if RecordList(5,i) <> RecordList(5,u) then
       Response.Write "<div class='Structure_Item_1'>" & RecordList(5,i) & "</div>" & vbCrLf
  end if
  if RecordList(4,i) <> RecordList(4,u) then
       Response.Write "<div class='Structure_Item_2'>" & RecordList(4,i) & "</div>" & vbCrLf
  end if
  Response.Write  "<div class='Structure_Item_3'>" & RecordList(3,i) & " " & RecordList(2,i) & "</div>" &vbCrLf
next
objRS.Close
objCon.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objCon = Nothing
Set objCom = Nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I get

```
Provider error '80040e14'

One or more errors occurred during processing of command.

/pagelets/structure.asp, line 25
```

when I do this. Is there an equivalent function?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is that LDAP somehow doesn't support GROUP BY; it's that your query isn't a valid GROUP BY query. Every column returned by the query must be *either* part of the grouping *or* an aggregated value. You can't have columns returned that are neither.

```
dim sql
sql = "SELECT Company, Department, Count(*) AS nUsers FROM '" & adUser & "'"
sql = sql & " WHERE company = '*' GROUP BY Company, Department"
sql = sql & " ORDER BY Company, Department"
```

(What's the purpose of `WHERE company = '*'`?)

That all said, I don't think you need to be grouping; you just need to be sorting.

```
sql = "SELECT company, department, givenName, sn, title, telephoneNumber"
sql = sql & " FROM '" & adUser & "' WHERE company Is Not NULL"
sql = sql & " ORDER BY company, department, givenName"
```